# Apps script wont let me use (row, column) notation with sheet.getRange

Tags: google-apps-script

var range = sheet.getRange(i, 1);

It only lets me use

var range = sheet.getRange('A1');

otherwise it gives me error message

Exception: The parameters (String,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.
addStats

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may [accept the answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that you believe is the best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells that the variable `sheet` does not refer to a sheet (tab) in the spreadsheet but to the whole spreadsheet.

The `.getRange('A1')` method exists with both sheet and spreadsheet objects. With a spreadsheet object, the method gets a range in the sheet that shows as the first one in the tab bar of the spreadsheet. The `.getRange(1, 1)` method, however, is only available with sheet objects.

To get a sheet object, use [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivesheet) or similar methods, like this:

```
 const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```